# If two different functions have same derivative and are equal at atleast 1 point then will the two fns be equal at all points in their mutual domain?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, trigonometry, complex-numbers

We know for$ f(x) = \arctan(x)$, $f'(x) = \dfrac1{x^2 + 1}$. Now we can write $x^2 + 1$ as $(x - i)\cdot(x + i)$ where $i = \sqrt{-1}$. So we can express $\dfrac1{x^2 + 1}$ as $\lambda\cdot\left(\dfrac1{x - i} - \dfrac1{x + i}\right)$ where $\lambda=\dfrac1{2i}$.

$$\begin{align}
\implies\arctan(x) &= \int\lambda\cdot\left(\dfrac1{x - i} - \dfrac1{x + i}\right)\mathrm dx \\
\implies\arctan(x) &= \lambda\cdot\ln\left|\dfrac{x - i}{x + i}\right| + c 
\end{align}$$
For $x=0$, we find that $c=0$.
$$\implies\arctan(x)=\lambda\cdot\ln\left|\dfrac{x - i}{x + i}\right|$$ for all values of $x$ where both functions are defined.
But according to wolfram alpha, the graphs of the two functions don't match so what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You have to take the complex logarithm if you're using complex numbers.  $$\arctan(z)=\frac{1}{2i}\log\left(\frac{z-i}{z+i}\right)$$  Look [here](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/archives/physics116A10/arc_10.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect as the domains on either side of the equality are different. If you assume that $x$ is real, how could you define $x-i$?

It would be OK if you wrote $z$ instead of $x$; taken as a variable in $\mathbb{C}$. Now try plotting both in W|A under this domain.